# Compare two ip subnet

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, ipv4, subnet

How to decide if two ip are on the same subnet or not?
The only input is the ip address and the subnet mask!
What is the optimal way, using **C/C++**, to compute if two ip have the same subnet?

Comment: Are you in an exam?

Comment: Apply the mask to the IP address and see if they're identical?

Comment: thank you marshal! then you mean to compute xor result between two ip or _xor_ between the two network ( ip _and_ subnet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool checkForSubnetEquality(in_addr_t ipA, in_addr_t ipB, uint32_t subnetMask) {
   return (ipA & subnetMask) == (ipB & subnetMask);
}
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

Bool CheckForSubnetParity(
BYTE[] _In_ iPAddress1, 
BYTE[] _In_ iPAddress2, 
BYTE[] _In_ subNetMask
) {

      BYTE[] NetworkPrefix1 = new BYTE[4];
      BYTE[] NetWorkPrefix2 = new BYTE[4];
      Bool Result = true;

      for ( int x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
      {
          NetworkPrefix1[x] = iPAddress1[x] && subNetMask[x];
          NetworkPrefix2[x] = iPAddress2[x] && subNetMask[x];
          if ( NetworkPrefix1[x] != NetworkPrefix2[x] ) 
          {
              Result = false;
          }
      }

      return Result;
   }
```

Comment: Allocating memory for this task is absolutely unnecessary! And I think `!=` has higher precedence than `^`, so this even seems to be wrong

Comment: You are absolutely right the `=` operator is much shorter expression for the same thing. I was getting wrapped up in such a narrow focus that I completely miss ' how to use equality' ...

Comment: But I do like to work with `BYTE` arrays as opposed to larger types.

Comment: That is stupid but if you insist at least get rid of the heap allocation: `BYTE NetworkPrefix1[4];`

Comment: That's not just a less verbose way of doing same thing?

Comment: Oh god no! new dynamically allocates memory (to get just a feel of all that is going  on under the hood scroll through: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/gen/malloc.c Don't even try to understand it just scroll through). The other way just uses a bit of the stack

Comment: Also you forgot to delete[] the buffers, so if that function is called repeatedly at some point the actual application runs out of memory -- that is called memory leak

Comment: They will be deleted automatically by the operating system once exited scope of them which would be when the function returns or completes.

Comment: I believe the issue arises when there is scope shifting (Bjarne (I'm on a first name basis (not really)) would probably not call it that) or what ever you would call it when a variable is passed on to another entity which uses it and it's original parent's scope is closed out but it's not tractable who is still using it cause it's not a neat stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132135/discussion-between-marshal-craft-and-user45891).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply 'xor' operation to both IP's using their mask and compare them after that. If they're identical, then both IP addresses in the same subnet.

Let's look at the 172.16.2.4/255.255.0.0 and 172.16.1.69/255.255.0.0
After 'xor' you'll get '172.16.0.0' for both addresses, so they are in the same subnet.

Regards.

Comment: Shouldn't it be AND instead of XOR?